# What will happen if i deactivate my visual composer plug in?

Tags: plugins, themes, premium

I have visual composer that is integrated in the River theme installed on my wordpress, the problem is, it is not working anymore, i want to update the theme but fear that the guy before me might have done some customization directly.  what do i do?

Comment: backup everything, deactivate it, and see what happens.

Comment: I think you need to update visual composer plugin, if you have older version.